# execute GitHub installation via bash on Colab

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install from a GitHub repo with bash code (the pip installation doesn't work).

I'm trying the following code (s. [here](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA#installation) for reference):

```
https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
cd GuidedLDA
sh build_dist.sh
python setup.py sdist
pip install -e .
```

which I adapted for Colab to

```
!https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
!cd GuidedLDA
!sh build_dist.sh
!python setup.py sdist
!pip install -e .
```

However, already the first line throws an Error: `/bin/bash: https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA: No such file or directory`

I am very new to bash, so apologies for rookie mistakes! I tried also

```
!"https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA"
!github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
!"github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA"
```

Then I tried using `xdg-open` with

```
!xdg-open https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
```

and

```
!apt-get install xdg-open
!xdg-open https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
```

all to no avail.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I used the git throw command.
it was difficult for me.
Now I use GitHub desktop.
it is too easy to handle everything.
you can check this playlist ->
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcL8q_TiioW0JLk03hM3cu_Nb5DRwBHa1